# Problem projecting data (d3) onto a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I am working on a project where I am trying to visualize data from a database onto a leaflet map. The data contains long/lat coodrinates, but when I'm trying to draw them onto the map, the location is all wrong or not showing at all.

I've read that the lat / long coordinates are not the same coordinates that are being used on the leaflet map, so i'm trying to translate them but with no luck.

The datebase has this structure (.csv file):

```
datetime,city,state,country,shape,durationSeconds,durationHours,comments,date_posted,latitude,longitude
10/10/1949 20:30,san marcos,tx,us,cylinder,2700,45 minutes,"This event took place in early fall around 1949-50. It occurred after a Boy Scout meeting in the Baptist Church. The Baptist Church sit",4/27/2004,29.8830556,-97.9411111
10/10/1949 21:00,lackland afb,tx,,light,7200,1-2 hrs,"1949 Lackland AFB&#44 TX.  Lights racing across the sky &amp; making 90 degree turns on a dime.",12/16/2005,29.38421,-98.581082
```

and the code so far looks like this:

```
 var map = L.map('mapid').setView([10, 15], 2.2);   L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/josecoto/civ8gwgk3000a2ipdgnsscnai/'
        +'tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9zZWNvdG8iLCJhIjoiY2l2OGZxZWNuMDAxODJ6cGdhcGFuN2IyaCJ9.7szLs0lc_2EjX6g21HI_Kg', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox.streets',
        accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
    }).addTo(map);

    var w = $("#mapid").width();
    var h = $("#mapid").height();     

    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
        .scale(w / 2 / Math.PI)
        .translate([w / 2, h / 2])

    function latLong(x,y)
    {      
        //console.log(x + ' and ' + y);
        var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
        return point;
    }  

    var svg_map = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

    svg_map.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            var coords = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]);
            return coords[0];
            //var coords = latLong(d.longitude, d.latitude);
            //return coords.x;    
            })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            var coords = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]);
            return coords[1];
            //var coords = latLong(d.longitude, d.latitude);
            //return coords.y;        
            })
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return 2;
         })
```

When I'm using the geoMercator() function, I can see the dots displayed on the map, however they are being projected onto the map wrong (because they are being bent from the function or something). And when I'm trying to use the latLong() function, they are not being displayed at all (but no errors in debugger).

I can add that I am getting the values from the database correctly, but the problem is in the vizualisation. Can you guys spot anything?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Here's an image of how it looks when I'm using the geoMercator:

[image: Map]

Comment: The Leaflet map is gonna snap your zoom level from `2.2` to `2` (because of [`zoomSnap`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-zoomsnap), so the width in pixels of 360 degrees of longitude is not the map's width, but rather... *checks math*... 1024 pixels. I'd try fiddling with your `w` and `h`, because the d3 SVG just looks stretched.

Comment: Hello Ivan, and thank you for your answer!
I will take a look and see if i can do anything with the w and h!

Comment: Well, it appered to be a problem with the dataset. Some entries in the list were undefined or equal. Javascript just stopped at those moments, and nothing got printed.